# Android layout fot soccer pitch with players

Tags: android

I wanna make a soccer pitch in an android activity which consists of the players position marked as in the real position.

Suggest a good layout solution which shows same in every screen size

Answer (score 1):

In Android every view adjusts to screen size or it's own limit
I suggest to use either SurfaceView or TextureView for android canvas
The TextureView has some advantages like transformation, scale
There is also GLSurfaceView for opengl drawing
Or try any game engine like Unity, Libgdx and others

Comment: This is not game app. This is a soccer score app. The football pitch is an image background in which I need to add players location

Comment: If they are static then use ImageView with needed scale type, in case of dynamic moving use above views

Comment: I tried with ImageView wrapped with constraint layout. The players icon changes it's position for different screen size